# javascript getFullYear() returns five digit

Tags: javascript, date

When i am trying to get date from timestamp using JavaScript, i am getting wrong year having five digits.

Here is the code:

```
var myTimeStamp = -2099709424;
var d = new Date(myTimeStamp * 1000);
var day = d.getDate(); // Returns correct date
var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // Returns correct month
var year = d.getFullYear(); // **Returns five digits**
var year1 = d.getYear(); // **Returns five digits**
var hour = d.getHours(); // Returns correct hours
var min = d.getMinutes();  // Returns correct minutes
var sec = d.getSeconds();  // Returns correct seconds
```

What is wrong over here?

Comment: What's the value of `myTimeStamp`?

Comment: Sorry `myTimeStamp = -2099709424`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `var myTimeStamp = -2099709424;` then make sure that you are having long int in input of `date`

```
var d = new Date(myTimeStamp);
```

Then try to get `d.getFullYear();`

Comment: Worked! I was returning `int` from `Java`

Comment: after setting `long int` i am getting `var myTimeStamp = 1367994858000;` and it works..

Answer (score 6):

It returns 5 digits because you are multiplying by 1000, there's no need to do that since you already have milliseconds if

```
myTimeStamp = 1367994858000;
```

as you said. Be careful to note that `myTimeStamp` should be a number, not a String.

Comment: Without multiplying with `1000`, it is returning `NaN`

Comment: @OP: Declare `myTimeStamp` as an integer. See the answer carefully.

Comment: I will make that explicit ;)

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni—if the value is a string, the [Date constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) will attempt to parse it.

Comment: See this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mabilalmirza/v8WjJ/. Don't forget to open your browser's console.

Comment: Sorry `myTimeStamp = -2099709424`, then it is giving me `1969` as year

Comment: @RobG new Date('1367994858000'); gives "Invalid Date" on both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni—because if you give the [Date constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) a string, it will try to parse it. If you want the value to be interpreted as milliseconds, you have to give it a number.

Comment: Ah yeah, I thought you were saying that it worked like that, ok fine :D

Answer (score 2):

As Alberto said:

```
var myTimeStamp = "1367994858000";

alert((new Date(+myTimeStamp).toUTCString())); // Wed, 08 May 2013 06:34:18 GMT
```

Your time value seems to be milliseconds already.